# Confusion about radioactivity

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, radiation, probability, radioactivity, kinetic-theory

The following question is from General Problems on Physics by I.E Irodov

> **6.220.** Find the decay constant and the mean lifetime of $^{55}\operatorname{Co}$ radionuclide if its activity is known to decrease $4.0\%$ per hour. The decay product is nonradioactive.

So, I was discussing this problem with my teacher and I believed I got the solution right (because the answer was correct) but my teacher kept on insisting that I can only use the following method for discrete intervals (in this case, for hours).

Here is the method I used

I determined that since the activity decreases each hour by $4\%$, The activity must be given by the following relation since every radioactive reaction follows an exponential function
$$A=A_o\left(\frac{96}{100}\right)^{t}$$
Where $t$ is in hours.

Since every first order decay reaction can be represented by the relation
$$A=A_oe^{-\lambda t}$$
Where $\lambda$ is the decay constant of the given substance.
Then, I equated the above relation
$$A_oe^{-\lambda t}=A_o\left(\frac{96}{100}\right)^{t}$$
On solving the relation, we obtain
$$\lambda=\ln\left(\frac{100}{96}\right )$$
To change the units into seconds,
$$\lambda=\frac{1}{3600}\ln\left(\frac{100}{96}\right )$$

Which is consistent with the given answer in the book. However, my teacher claims this method is incorrect. Is this method correct?

Comment: Don't be confused by teachers, their minds sometimes work in strange ways ;). Your solution is perfectly fine and your reasoning sound. Some polishing could be be done: You can add the units throughout the calculation by changing the exponent in the first equation to $\frac{t}{1\,\mathrm{h}}$. Then you won't have to keep track of the units separately. (But get the result $\lambda = - \ln(0.96)\,\mathrm{h^{-1}} = - \frac{\ln(0.96)}{3600}\,\mathrm{s^{-1}}$).

Comment: Thanks, I was getting increasingly bewildered because the more I looked at the solution, the more I improved upon the solution to make it more clear (Since I thought up this solution in my mind, and my thoughts are very chaotic), I expected to find some error but was unable to find any. The more worrying part was that if there was in fact, an error in my reasoning, and I was unable to find it, it would mean that I have a pretty fundamental problem in my understanding of the subject.

Comment: Wait is the method you show the one your teacher suggested or the one you used?  You stated `...my teacher kept on insisting that I can only use the following method...` so I was looking for the method that your teacher demand you use.

Comment: @honeste_vivere, Sorry for the ambiguity, I came up with this method but my teacher said that it is valid only for discrete intervals of integer multiples of hours and thus not a valid method to solve this question.

Comment: @AvZ - I assume the teach assumes that the "only" way to solve this problem is through the typical approach.  Namely, just use two equations, with inserted values, at two different times (in your case, make it easy and choose one hour).